# Converting a data frame from a long to wide format

Tags: r, dataframe, format

I am trying to change a data frame from a long to wide format.

My data frame:

```
species   site   abundance
  A        1         0
  B        1         2
  C        1         8
  D        1         1
  A        2         4
  B        2         0   
  C        2         0
  D        2         0
  A        3         1
  B        3         2
  C        3         8
  D        3         1
```

What I am trying to achieve is a species by site abundance data frame:

```
site   A      B      C     D    
 1     0      2      8     1 
 2     4      0      0     0
 3     1      2      8     1
```

I have tried using the *transpose* function from base R, the *melt* and *dcast* functions from reshape2, and the *pivot_wider* function from tidyr:

```
t(my.df) #transpose

melt(my.df, id.vars = "site", 
            variable.name = "spp", value.name = "abundance") #rehsape2

dcast(my.df, "species" ~ "site", value.var = "abundance") #rehsape2

my.df %>%
  pivot_wider(names_from = spp, values_from = abundance, values_fn = list) #tidyr
```

Im not sure if I am doing something wrong and I cannot find other functions to try.
Any help is appreciated.

Comment: To help others, help you , `dput(head(my_dataframe, n = ?))` and replace your data.frame above by pasting `structure(....)` above, as your data.frame, as it makes helping easier.

Comment: Your codes for melt and pivot_wider refer to `spp` which is not a column in the example data.

Comment: You mention what you want and what you tried, but we don't know what result you got (including any errors if applicable) and how that varied from what you wanted.

Comment: Your pivot_wider code works fine for me if I use `species` instead of `spp` and remove the `values_fn = list` part.